# Emacs Orgmode function to return last subheading

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Does anyone know of a function that will return the last subheading of a tree?  I have a capture template set up for journal entries, but the subheading I want them to be filed under is dynamic (changes for each work rotation where the most current is the last in the list).  So my capture template target needs to be (file+function "path/to/file" function-finding-location) where the "function-finding-location" finds the last subheading of a given top level header.

* Log Book 
** 2018-01-01 to 2018-01-29
** 2018-02-26 to 2018-03-26
*** New Journal Entry to go here

Comment: Is that different from the end of the file/buffer? Capture normally appends at the target location - are you sure you need to do anything? Also, have you tried a datetree capture template? It might be just what you need for a log book.

Comment: Tks for the suggestion regarding default target location being the end.  I noticed the "type" item in the documentation.  Turns out all I needed to do was use "file" instead of "file+headline" use "plain" instead of "entry", put the correct number of asterisks in front of "template" portion and now my new entry is in the correct location and at the correct level as long as I keep my "Log Book" top level headline at the end of my todo.org file.  Not an ideal solution, but it works.  I previously used "file+headline" - entry was in proper location, but wasn't at the proper level.

Comment: You should investigate the datetree option as well: it might be a better fit.